# How to calculate time spent (Timestamp) query, in T-SQL , SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

[image]
How I can query data from this type of table to calculate time spent by user in each session..

for example for user A time spent should be  time of activity 3 minus time of activity 1.

Comment: It's better sample data and expected data as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you've tried so far but based on your sample data, try this:

```
SELECT 
    UserID, SessionID, 
    MIN(timestamp) StartTime, MAX(timestamp) EndTime,
    DATEDIFF(s,MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp)) SecondsDifference
FROM 
    Table
GROUP BY 
    UserID, SessionID
```

This kind of data is usually tricky because you don't have the luxury of a sessionid, or the sessionid doesn't truly reflect what you're trying to measure